# What's the iterator types of sequence containers?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer

As I read through *The C++ Programming Language*, I found this paragraph saying

> The iterator passed to *inserter()* must be an iterator into the container. For a sequence container, that implies that it must be **a bidirectional iterator** (so that you can insert before it). For example, you can’t use *inserter()* to make an iterator to insert into a *forward_list*...

So I started to find the relative parts of the standard that would verify this statement. However, I was left with this paragraph (23.2.6 [associative.reqmts] paragraph 6) relating to only **associative container**:

> iterator of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator category...

Where can I find the iterator types of **sequence containers** in the standard?

Comment: Not _The standard_, but a [good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm also aware of std::iterator_traits, but I think that's done in compile-time. Do you mean to say that the iterator types of sequence containers are implementation-defined so that they can't be stated in the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard states that for sequence containers separately. e.g.

For [forward_­list](http://eel.is/c++draft/forwardlist.overview#1):

> A `forward_­list` is a container that supports forward iterators and ...

For [deque](http://eel.is/c++draft/deque.overview#1):

> A `deque` is a sequence container that supports random access iterators ([[random.access.iterators](http://eel.is/c++draft/random.access.iterators)]).

You can expect that the iterator category for sequence containers are at least forward iterator category.

Comment: It seems the iterators of other sequence containers are _implementaion-defined_. I'm a bit curious, although they are _implementation-defined_, are there any sort of lower bounds that guarantee some level of iterators for those containers.

Comment: @Il-seobBae They're not implementation-defined, the standard just specifies them separately. In N4606 there's a statement for sequence container, "iterator and const_iterator types for sequence containers shall be at least of the forward iterator category."

Comment: @Il-seobBae - the **actual type** of the iterator is unspecified; implementations write their own type. (That's not "implementation-defined", because the standard says that when something is implementation defined the implementation **must document what it does**). The standard **requires** that the iterator meet certain requirements, such as being a forward iterator or a random access iterator. That constrains what the implementation can do, without requiring any particular implementation.